# Can we close oracle forms connection from Java application

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data, oracleforms

We are modernizing the legacy oracle forms to microservices(spring boot/REST API's)

in few table inserts the triggers are throwing post insert errors, and the current team is suggesting to use

*begin
HST9I.qms_transaction_mgt.open_transaction( p_trans_opened_by => 'FORM');//(trigger code)*
**our updates to tables here**
*HST9I.qms_transaction_mgt.close_transaction( p_trans_opened_by => 'FORM');
end;//trigger code*

But as we have the connections and transactions managed by spring, how can we close/open the connections like above.
Any suggestions on how to approach?